# Google Colab Crashing when trying to compute second order derivatives

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using google colab to implement a Physics-Informed Neural Network. I upgraded my Colab to System RAM of 12.7 GB and Disk of 107.7 GB. However, when computing the loss function, I am getting the following error: Your session crashed after using all available RAM.

This is my code:

```
def compute_loss(model, grid_points, real_OSM_values_Circle_tensor):
  #Compute physics based loss
  physics_based_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(get_residual(model,grid_points)))

  #initialise loss
  loss = physics_based_loss

  #Add physics_based_loss and data loss
  for i in range(len(real_OSM_values_Circle_tensor)):
    u_pred = model(grid_points[i:i+1,:])
    loss += tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(u_pred - real_OSM_values_Circle_tensor[i]))
  return loss


#model = init_model()
#compute_loss(model, grid_points, real_OSM_values_Circle_tensor)

def get_grad(model,grid_points):
  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    #This tape is for derivatives with respect to trainable variables
    tape.watch(model.trainable_variables)
    loss = compute_loss(model, grid_points, real_OSM_values_Circle_tensor)
  g = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  del tape

  return loss, g

lr = 0.001
# Choose the optimizer
optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)

# Define one training step as a TensorFlow function to increase speed of training
@tf.function
def train_step():
  # Compute current loss and gradient w.r.t. parameters
  loss, grad_theta = get_grad(model,grid_points)

  # Perform gradient descent step
  optim.apply_gradients(zip(grad_theta, model.trainable_variables))

  return loss

# Number of training epochs
N = 1
hist = []

# Start timer
t0 = time()

for i in range(N+1):

  loss = train_step()

  # Append current loss to hist
  hist.append(loss.numpy())
  """
  # Output current loss after 50 iterates
  if i%50 == 0:
      print('It {:05d}: loss = {:10.8e}'.format(i,loss))
  """
  print('It {:05d}: loss = {:10.8e}'.format(i,loss))
# Print computation time
print('\nComputation time: {} seconds'.format(time()-t0))
```

When I try initialising a model and running it, the code seems to get stuck on line  `loss = train_step()`. I tried setting up a really simple NN and the number of epochs to 1 just to ensure the code runs but even then I am getting the same error. Should I upgrade the RAM or is there a way to make my code more efficient (len(real_OSM_values_Circle_tensor) = 22500).

Changed a lot simpler neural network, lower epoch number.